# Mysql query dosen't provide the result needed

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to figure this one out for days but can't come up with a solution. 
Here are the table schemes.

[image: table schemes]

This is my current query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `address`, `order`.`id` 
  FROM `order`, `ordered_articles`
 WHERE `order`.`id` = `f_order_id`
   AND `Status` > 1
   AND `Status` <4;
```

The problem is that the query returns as long as there is one article with status bigger than 1. I need a query where all the articles of that order have a status bigger than 1.

Comment: When rows source consists from more than one table then specify table alias for each column name in the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT o.`address`, o.`id` 
FROM `order` o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM `ordered_articles`
  WHERE `f_order_id` = o.`id`
  AND (`Status` <= 1 OR `Status` >= 4 )
);
```

or:

```
SELECT o.`address`, o.`id` 
FROM `order` o INNER JOIN `ordered_articles` i
ON i.`f_order_id` = o.`id`
GROUP BY o.`address`, o.`id`
HAVING SUM(`Status` <= 1 OR `Status` >= 4) = 0;
```

Comment: They produce a different output but the 2nd query works for me. Thanks a lot.